# Is the switch example usage in airbnb javascript guide inconsistent?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, airbnb-js-styleguide

I'm catching up on javascript that I have not used since some time, doing so by inspiring most of my coding style from the Modern Javascript [coding guide by AirBnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#comparison--switch-blocks)

In the [paragraph regarding `switch`](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#comparison--switch-blocks) I think there is an inconsistency. But that's not as if the Airbnb guide had been read by tons of guy before me...

Check the line for `case 4` which alone does not use curly braces, but rather no braces at all like in the style before which is considered bad. However the `default` case comes back at using curly braces.

```
switch (foo) {
  case 1: {
    let x = 1;
    break;
  }
  case 2: {
    const y = 2;
    break;
  }
  case 3: {
    function f() {
      // ...
    }
    break;
  }
  case 4:
    bar();
    break;
  default: {
    class C {}
  }
}
```

If it is not an inconsistency, then what would be the sound reason for this different `case 4` ?

Comment: Braces are not required. Without knowing the purpose of that example code it's really hard to comment beyond that; the code makes little sense and if anything it looks like an example of things to *not* do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inconsistency. The curly braces are used as a scope for the lexical declarations. Case 4 is the only case without any such declaration.